# AWS Backup reports autogenerate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Does amazon ec2 generate emails and pdfs of the monitoring information which it does on regular timely basis ? It provides some graphs for CPU Utilisation, Disk reads, Dish reads information, Disk write, Disk write oprations, Network in etc. I need to get all these graphs and data from aws console to my email address in the form of pdf.Can i get it directly or if there is another way to get backup on regular basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the metrics from EC2 are stored in CloudWatch (with most other AWS service metrics). Unfortunately there is no export feature built in so you either need to make one using the CloudWatch api/cli or use someone else's

https://github.com/petezybrick/awscwxls

The following is a good starting point for collecting the EC2 metrics, before creating the graphs if you want to do it on your own.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html

Option 3 is to script a login and screenshot of the AWS Console on the metrics page in a browser

Comment: Okay. Thanks a ton. So this is the only way to get backup information right ?

Comment: Yes, but recently the CloudWatch metrics retention period was extended from 14 days to 15 months, so maybe you no longer need your own backup? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-update-extended-metrics-retention-user-interface-update/